# Integration or unit test

Tags: laravel

It is not quite clear to me when I should use integrations and unit test

If I want to test the following code without making any http requests, should I use an integration test or unit ?

When a thread is created, the activity is recorded and an email event is fired

```
ThreadObserver extends Observer
{
    public function created(Thread $thread)
    {
        Activity::record($thead);
        event(new ThreadWasCreated($thread);
     }
}
```

```
class RecordsActivityTest
{
    public function it_records_the_acitivty_when_a_thread_is_created()
    {
        Thread::factory()->create();
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('activities', […]);
   
    }
    

}
```

Another example, I want to test that give a query it returns the expected results .

```
class Search
{
     public function __construct(protected Index $index)
     {
            
      }

      public function handle($query)
      {
            $this->index->search($query);
             // more code 
       }
}
```

```
class SearchTest
{
    public function it_returns_the_expected_result()
    {
        $search = new Search(new Index);
        $results = $search->handle(“some query”);
        $this->assertEquals(“some
    Data”);
    }

}
```

Do I need a unit test, to test the `Search` class or an integration test because it is dependent on another class ?

Comment: Testing categories are vague and opinionated. To get an idea of Laravel's opinion, I believe the artisan command to create a Unit test extends the plain phpunit test class, whereas the Feature/Integration test extends the Laravel base class. What this means is a unit test is isolated enough not to need the service container, but a Integration test would be able to use any Laravel feature.

Answer (score 1):

The first example, I'd most likely write an integration test, but instead of testing if the database has a value, I'd just mock the event https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#event-fake and assert that the event was dispatched.

The second example however, it could go either way. You can write a unit test and just mock everything OR, you could write an integration test so you can use the Laravel helpers, specifically the https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#http-fake if you're testing an API, otherwise mockery if you're testing and SDK for example.

Comment: Isn't the point of the integration test to test the actual classes that are involved, instead of mocking everything ? So in the 2nd example, what would you mock. Taking into consideration that they are not making any http requests, instead they they search the database.